# Как возвращать определенные поля из связанной таблицы в Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

Связь установлена через hasOne. Есть такой код:

```
$flights_to = Flights::where('from_id', $airports_fromid)->with('airports_from')->first();
return response()->json($flights_to, 200);
```

Который возвращает такой результат:

```
{
"id": 1,
"flight_code": "FP2100",
"from_id": 2,
"to_id": 1,
"time_from": "08:35:00",
"time_to": "10:05:00",
"cost": 10500,
"created_at": null,
"updated_at": null,
"airports_from": {
    "id": 2,
    "city": "Moscow",
    "name": "Sheremetyevo",
    "iata": "SVO",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
}
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы возвращались не все поля, а только определенные, например перечислить все кроме "created_at" и "updated_at"?

Comment: Как вариант, использовать пакет [Laravel-query-builder](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-query-builder/v3/introduction). Там есть опция выбора определенных полей.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Такие задачи лучше решать при помощи JSON-ресурсов (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources).

```
$flight = Flights
    ::where('from_id', $airports_fromid)
    ->with('airports_from')
    ->first();
 
return new FlightResource($flight);
```

Сам класс:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class FlightResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'flight_code' => $this->flight_code,
            'from_id' => $this->from_id,
            'to_id' => $this->to_id,
            'time_from' => $this->time_from,
            'time_to' => $this->time_to,
            'cost' => $this->cost,
            'airports_from' => [
                'id' => $this->airports_from->id,
                'city' => $this->airports_from->city,
                'name' => $this->airports_from->name,
                'iata' => $this->airports_from->iata,
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Да!!! Именно то, что нужно. Тысячи лучей благодарности! :)
Извиняюсь что поздно принял ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Может помочь метод `select()`:

```
$flights_to = Flights::select(
        'id',
        'flight_code',
        'from_id',
        'to_id',
        'time_from',
        'time_to',
        'cost',
        'airports_from'
    )
        ->where('from_id', $airports_fromid)
        ->with('airports_from')
        ->first();
```

Детальнее о методе здесь: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#select-statements

Comment: Спасибо! Стало лучше, но к сожалению в объекте "airports_from", заключенном в with так и приходит вся строка с базы со всеми ненужными полями

Comment: тогда попробуйте поиграть с видимостями полей: для конкретного обьекта через `makeHidden()` метод (подробнее: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#temporarily-modifying-attribute-visibility) либо вообще для всех моделей этого типа через $hidden атрибут модели (подробнее: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)